# makeindex style of the book TeXbyTopic

Tags: errors, makeindex

What's the makeindex style of the book "[TeXbyTopic](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/texbytopic)"?

I use the default style `makeindex TeXbyTopic.idx` to produce the `ind` file
and there are many "Input index error"s in the log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Replace

```
\def\cstoidx#1\par{\index{#1@\cs{#1}@}}
```

with

```
\def\cstoidx#1\par{\index{#1@\cs{#1}}}
```

#### Long answer

The problem raises because of

```
\def\cstoidx#1\par{\index{#1@\cs{#1}@}}
```

that produces invalid entries in the `.idx` file.

If I change the code into

```
\def\cstoidx#1\par{\index{#1@\cs{#1}}}
```

then the index is produced without errors. Here's the start of the index I obtain

[image]

Let's compare it with the index that appears in the version of the book shipped with TeX Live, where all the control sequences are missing.

[image]